# How to check solr server restarted sucessfully or not?

Tags: java, linux, solr

I am writing an automate script, where I am restarting solr servers one by one. But some time they are not restarting.

I am using the below command to restart it:

```
stopsolr; //stoping the solar server
cd $SolrFolder; //going to index folder
unzip -o $solrindex; //extracting the index
sleep 240; //waiting some time
startsolr" >> $SolrLog;//starting server
```

Now I want to check if the server started or not. If not started, then I want to stop my script from execution and will return an error code. I am vary new to Linux environment/shell scripting. Which command I can use to check the status of solr server?

Comment: If this is for production use, please evaluate likes of Chef, puppet , saltstack, rundeck...

Answer (score 0):

you can do something along the lines of:

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/core0/select/?q=*%3A*
```

parse the response, and verify numfound= your expected number, or numfound> X if you don't know the size for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Solr has a ping handler which is handy to use when you want to check status of a Solr instance programmatically. SolrCloud uses this to keep handle on its cluster.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/ping
```

look for status "ok". This is exactly the purpose this handler.

More about it here : http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_1_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/handler/PingRequestHandler.html